# Using iOS, Tiled, Box2D and XCode. Problems importing my own .tmx files

Tags: objective-c, ios

So I'm getting the error "TMX: unsupported compression method" using [this tutorial's code](http://www.uchidacoonga.com/2011/01/side-scrolling-the-background-in-box2d/) and any of my own created TMX tiled map editor files.

I was just trying to figure out how to use tiled to make interesting maps, since I am creating a side scrolling game I was using this as a reference.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Tiled has multiple compression modes for saving - under File -> Preferences -> Store tile layer data as: for iOS and Box2D, this should be set to Base64 (gzip compressed).